# Visual Studio 2010 blurry font

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual C# 2010 Express (final, not beta or anything) and I'm having an issue with blurry fonts while debugging. The font appears normal everywhere (intellisense, menus, code) but when a breakpoint is reached most of the debugger related text is blurry (Locals, Call Stack, "data tooltips").

Here are screenshots of the normal text and the blurry text while debugging:
http://img682.imageshack.us/i/normalh.png/

http://img145.imageshack.us/i/blurry.png/

Is this a known bug or something related to my system? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: The two images are about the same sharpness to my eye.

Comment: I don't see it from the pictures. You got any more of that ?

Comment: I do see the difference (make sure you zoom in on the images).  Looks like ClearType to me.  If you don't like it, try disabling ClearType on a system level, or switch to a non-ClearType font.

Comment: The screenshots look the same to me too.  Maybe the debugger is putting the screen into a non-native resolution?  That would make it look like crap on the screen, but the screenshot would look normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have to change the setting of "Fonts and Colors"

1. Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors
2. pick the item of "[Watch, Locals,
   and Autos Tool Windows]" from "Show
   setting for"
3. Change the Font and Size to the
   setting as same as the setting of
   "Text Editor"

Comment: That was it, I can't believe I missed the show setting for drop down! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

guys.

Like a JTeck, my VS showed blurry fonts in any scenaries. I solved this problem going to "Tools\Options". In "Environment\General" I uncheck all options in "Visual experience".

This is solve my problem. I hope that can help you too.

Comment: Helps for VS 2013. Font in text editor is too sharp now (like no antialiasing or some smoothing), but not too blurry.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar blurring issue but the code in my text editor only got blurry when I would hit the enter key, the shifting of the text somehow triggered it. I tried all the above solutions but it did not solve the problem.

The only thing that seems to have worked was changing my Font Size from 10 to 9.

As for the ClearType On/Off issue, it looks like VS 2010 forces ClearType on for Consolas (and only Consolas) regardless of your system settings.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/15/visual-studio-2010-text-clarity-cleartype-and-aliased-fonts.aspx

There is a TextSharp VS extension mentioned in there that can override the ClearType setting and may help stop Consolas from blurring.

I imported my 2010 ide settings to VS2012 and didn't see the same problem oddly, so I'm guessing MS has resolved it somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this appears to be not ClearType but WPF font smoothing. The difference is significant. ClearType doesn't do blurry, at least not on a standard LCD screen, it uses subpixels to anti-alias the fonts. When ClearType is disabled at the system level, WPF still renders using greyscale anti-aliasing. Try *enabling* ClearType.

Comment: It seems only a few fonts render that way, changing from Segoe UI to Tahoma did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The blurry text is a different font, and it's being rendered using ClearType. Some ClearType rendering, on some displays, with some fonts, at some point sizes looks unpleasantly blurry--that's what you've got.

You can change the font (in the Options menu) to a different face, or a larger size. It will also improve if you use a higher-resolution display.

Answer (score 0):

I just opened up Visual Studio 2010 for the first time and got what i considered to be blurry font - for all scenarions, not just when debugging.

I simply switched the Font (Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors) from 'Consolas' to 'Courier New' and all was well...

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue has to do with the monitor or screen. I am using two so moved the blurry VS window to the second monitor and everything looks fine.

If this is your case too, then try to calibrate your screen by adjusting the settings.