# Visual Studio Community 2015 blurry on second monitor to Surface Pro 4

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, monitor

My surface pro 4 display is 2736×1824, scaling 200%. The external monitor I plugged in on HDMI is 1920x1080, scaling 100%.

Other apps (such as Chrome) display OK on the external monitor, but Visual Studio text editor is very blurry - so blurry that my eyes kept trying to refocus and became very tired very quickly.

So I basically had to turn off the large monitor and work only on the surface's own display.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010 blurry font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659700/visual-studio-2010-blurry-font)

Comment: Not sure if it will work, but try this: Right click on VS in the start menu and select "More" and then "Open File Location". Right click on the VS exe (or shortcut) in file explorer and click "Properties".  Select the "Compatibility" tab. Under "Settings", check the "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" option and then close the properties dialog. Launch VS as you would normally.

Comment: None of the things above worked

Comment: I got exactly the same thing with a 4K monitor next to a 1980x1200. VS really sucks at this. It is in every version, also 2017 Enterprise. What might help is setting both displays to the same dpi, rendering your surface useless but at least you can work on an external display.

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me: ensure that your high resolution display is *not* your primary. Set one of your other / Full HD displays as primary, and reboot -- the reboot is unfortunately required.

Comment: This works! For future readers - no need for a full reboot, but you do need to sign out and back into Windows.

Comment: Pretty sure that the problem is simply not signing out after making display changes: I opened Display Settings and there was a red message stating something along the lines of "_some apps may not respond to changes until you sign out_", but it's somewhat easy to miss (or maybe it doesn't show up until you reopen that screen - not sure).

Comment: Can't believe this actually worked...  The first though I had was, what if I set the first screen to main screen again and then logout/login. Will it go back to being blurry? To save you that test...  The fix is permanent, even when you reset the first screen to be the main screen.

Comment: I don't understand how Microsoft test Windows 10 on Surface 4 Pro. It's an very expensive device!

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the scale of 'text apps and other items' to 100% for all of your monitors.
Open 'Settings' of windows 10 and go to the 'Display' and find 'Change the size of text, apps, and other items:' to set its scale to 100%.
Yes it can make you hard to read text on your high resolution (but small in physical size) monitor. So, it's your choice as

Comment: This is totally impossible. The resolution of Surface Pro 4 is so high, and text at 100% on the tablet is so tiny, it is virtually impossible.